# How can I determine the MAC address for a NIC in CentOS without using ifconfig?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, mac-address, network-adapter

CentOS 5.5

One of my CenTOS systems recently booted with the following error:

"Bringing up interface eth0: Device eth0 has difference MAC address than expected. ignoring."

When I run **ifconfig -a** there's no entry for eth0 and I'm reasonably certain that the static HWADDR entry in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 is incorrect.

Are there alternate ways for definitively determining what the correct MAC addresses are via the command-line? I was wondering if perhaps lspci could help?  I don't have hwinfo available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if there is no entry in `ifconfig -a`... that means the device is not detected in the machine... (either due to missing driver support or bad/mis-identified hardware)  check `dmesg` to confirm that "eth0" is detected by the system at all.  You can also `lspci` to list all devices attached to the system... and look for unknown devices and/or your ethernet controller.

Comment: +1 TheCompWiz. This was very helpful to me. Thank you!

Comment: `lspci -vvv` gives you lots of extra information.

Comment: lspci can be useful... unless it's a usb-ethernet adapter... lsusb works for usb... I was trying to keep the answer generic.

Answer (score 14):

for CentOS 7:

```
ip a
```

in my box, the MAC comes after 'link/ether'

ex:

link/ether cc:10:ee:5f:d8:aa

Answer (score 13):

You can use:

For all interfaces:

```
cat /sys/class/net/*/address
```

For ethernet0 interface:

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2018/01/linux-saber-direccion-mac.html

Answer (score 4):

The other answers above are good for a working interface, but if you're trying to find the MAC to configure a new interface--e.g. you swap the NIC--Dwight's answer is the key. Thanks Dwight!

You mentioned `ifcfg-eth0` value being incorrect--I also had that problem because I replaced the motherboard. I did the:

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address
```

command and used the output to:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

and change the `HWADDR` value, and after running `ifup eth0`, the interface began working.